# How to serialize text that contains mixed HTML & XML to a string?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, xml

This might be ridiculous, but I have a C# function that returns a string to JavaScript via AJAX. The first part of the string is HTML, and the second part is XML. The string will look something like:

```
"""
<b>Some HTML</b> - this entire string is returned from the server.
<i>I have no control over it</i>.

<br/>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
 </catalog>
</xml>
"""
```

Then I have a function that creates a jQuery UI modal dialogue that contains this string as the main text. It correctly renders the first part as HTML, but the second part (the XML) is invisible

**What I need** is to render the HTML as it is now, but also render out the XML as a plaintext string (as you see in the example above). Ideally, I would like a server-side solution, but I am guessing it has to be client-side.

I would use something like `new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(combinedString)` but won't that also get rid of the HTML tags?

**Note:** I do not know the HTML text ahead of time. I don't know if it will be seperated by newlines, `<p>` tags, `<div>`'s, or whatever else, so I can't exactly do something like `String.Split('\n')`.

Comment: `I have a C# function that returns a string` Why don't you return an array/list of strings. First element html and the second xml.

Comment: "This *might* be ridiculous"? It *is* ridiculous - if you control C# code return something that makes sense and easy to parse like JSON object with HTML and XML as separate properties or correctly encoded HTML. Please clarify why you need such strange output and what are other restrictions.

Comment: You need to extract the text for the tag <?xml> and its children.  Then parse the extracted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should HTML encode the XML portion in the server side before returning the result to the client. Use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode function to complete this task.

For further details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nice... I can't believe I forgot about this utility. Exactly what I needed!